# Como adicionar um evento a um icon?

Tags: java, swing, icons

Eu queria fazer com que ao clicar sobre um ícone fosse possível abrir uma tela, executar um ação qualquer e etc.

Eu queria colocar formatos diferentes, por isso não uso um `JButton`. Pois ao passar a imagem para ele, ele continuou "retangular". Mais, no caso de existir algum componente que possa assumir a forma de uma imagem ou mesmo fazer com o JButton, também é válido.

Exemplo clicar sobre um pequeno circulo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package pacote01;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NovoClass extends JFrame
{    
    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public NovoClass()
    {
        setSize(200, 150);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icone.png"));   
        JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image); 

        painel.add(imagelabel);
        add(painel);   
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovoClass novo = new NovoClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para adicionar um `listener` em um `jLabel` você pode usar o `addMouseListener`, passando como parâmetro uma implementação de `MouseListener` chamado `MouseAdapter`, fazendo a sobre-escrita apenas no método `mouseClicked`.

Segue abaixo o trecho responsável por isso:

```
imagelabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("clicou no icone");
    }
});
```

Segue abaixo o codigo completo

```
public class NovoClass extends JFrame {
    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public NovoClass() {
        setSize(200, 150);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/icone.png"));
        JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image);
        //Adiciona o mouse listener
        imagelabel.addMouseListener(getMouseListener());

        painel.add(imagelabel);
        add(painel);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    //Cria o mouse listener
    public MouseListener getMouseListener() {
        //Utiliza a implementação do mouseAdapter
        return new MouseAdapter() {
            //Faz a sobre-escrita apenas no click
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("clicou no icone");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovoClass novo = new NovoClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: primeiramente obrigado ! Apenas por "conhecimento", sabe me dizer se um JButton ou outro componente assume a forma de um icon ?

Comment: Na verdade não, o mais próximo que você consegue fazer é colocar um ícone dentro do `JButton` pelo método `setIcon` desta maneira: `jbutton.setIcon(image);`. Porém ele é apenas um botão com um ícone centralizado

Comment: Certo, é que eu queria mudar o ponteiro do mouse, mais, pelo que eu acabei de ler, parece que é só sobrescrever um determinado método, quando eu passar por cima do icone.

Comment: Legal, na realidade você consegue alterar o cursor do mouse ao passar sobre um `JLabel`, você pode usar o método `setCursor` e adicionar o cursor desejado ao jLabel, desta maneira: `imagelabel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));`, este exemplo ele deixa o cursor no JLabel com uma mãozinha (`Cursor.HAND_‌​CURSOR`), mais dentro do `Cursor` você pode selecionar outro modelo dos que já são predefinidos

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar !